# Elementary OS Updates issue

Tags: updates

I just installed elementary OS 5.0. This AM when I try sudo apt-get update

I get the below message, and also when I try to use the Software Updater, I got the same message with an additional line at the end:

> E:The repository
>   'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu
>   bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

sudo apt-get update

```
Obj:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Obj:2 mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                              
Ign:3 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                    
Des:4 packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic InRelease [5 894 B]                                        
Obj:5 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                         
Obj:6 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                               
Obj:7mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                            
Obj:8 dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                      
Ign:9 ppa.launchpad.net/grabli66-r/eos/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                           
Obj:10 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease                                               
Obj:11 mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-proposed InRelease                                            
Des:12 packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [165 kB]                       
Obj:13 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                
Obj:15 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                              
Ign:16 ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Obj:17 ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Obj:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/grabli66-r/eos/ubuntu bionic Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Err:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho                
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (multiverse/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/grabli66-r/eos/ubuntu bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (universe/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:48 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:46 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-i386/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-es_MX) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-es) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo Translations (multiverse/i18n/Translation-en) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11 (multiverse/dep11/Components-all.yml) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-small (multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo DEP-11-icons-large (multiverse/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
W: El objetivo CNF (multiverse/cnf/Commands-all) está configurado varias veces en /etc/apt/sources.list:50 y /etc/apt/sources.list:52
```

Comment: I delete the duplicate entries the error message is showing, and now I got the following error message:  E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/grabli66-r/eos/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: I also tried the following with no success:     sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:versable/elementary-update    
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
E: No se pudo bloquear /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Recurso no disponible temporalmente)
E: No se pudo bloquear el directorio /var/lib/apt/lists/